# Asus laptop not connecting to Kobuki base?

Tags: turtlebot, ubuntu, asus, ubuntu-trusty, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Asus Laptop doesn't seem to see the Kobuki base.  When I use the command
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
I get a Device does not (yet) available on this port, waiting....

The laptop is connected via the USP printer port on the kobuki.  Does anyone have an idea what might be at issue?

I've run out of ideas Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242680/asus-laptop-not-connecting-to-kobuki-base?/) by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Needed the udev rules,
. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

> rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules

Works fine now......

---

Originally posted by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) with karma: 51 on 2016-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0